# how does one go about copying one xml document's node to another?

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to insert an element node (that has some children) from one XML into another in java.

What I'm trying (which isn't working) looks like this...

```
Node foo = document1.getChildNodes().item(3).cloneNode(true);

document2.getChildNodes().item(2).appendChild(foo);
```

I'm getting an exception that complains that i'm trying to use a node created by one document in another.

Is there an alternative, short of recursing through doc1's node and creating the whole thing manually in doc2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I hate asking questions, thinking I've hit a wall, and then suddenly just stumbling on the answer that was there in front of me the whole time!

document.importNode() does the trick nicely.... thanks me! :)